# Retrieving content using Beautifulsoup and selectors

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

Trying to retrieve content (text) embedded in html.  Not getting the content.

Trying to use selector in the format to find price_box:
`price_box = soup2.find('div', attrs={'title class': 'Fw(600)'})`

```
# Import libraries
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Set the URL you want to webscrape from
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NVDA?p=NVDA'

# Connect to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup object¶
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

beta = soup.find('h1')
#print (beta)

link = beta.contents

variable = 'NVDA - NVIDIA Corporation'
test = 'NVDA - NVIDIA Corporation'

#<..>

url2 = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?from=2019-09-01&to=2019-09-07&day=2019-09-01'

response2 = requests.get(url2)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(response2.text, "html.parser")
# alpha = soup2.find('')

# div = soup.find('a', {class_ ='D(ib) '})
# text = div.string

price_box = soup2.find('div', attrs={'title class': 'Fw(600)'})
#price = price_box.text
print("Price Box: "+ str(price_box)) # THIS IS WHAT I WANT
```

Was hoping to see "Senea".  Instead seeing "None" - "Price Box: 
None"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the content is dynamic. You can regex out that info easily

```
import requests, re

p = re.compile(r'"YFINANCE:(.*?)"')
r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?from=2019-09-01&to=2019-09-07&day=2019-09-01&guccounter=1')
print(p.findall(r.text)[0])
```

An alternate is to avoid the dynamic looking classes altogether

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?from=2019-09-01&to=2019-09-07&day=2019-09-01&guccounter=1')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('#cal-res-table a').text)
```

---

**Reading:**

1. [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Comment: QHarr, I'm still way behind in regex but I won't be stuck here long. LOL!

Comment: @sim Did you look at those youtube links I gave? Also, I dip into [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) but haven't dedicated the time to go through it all properly.

Comment: Yeah, the content within the link is a treasure. Will explore it deeply. Thanks.

Comment: Question: How did you know that the content was dynamic?  Sorry, very new to all this.

Comment: Holy crap your solution worked!!  Two questions: 1) Why did you add "&guccounter=1" to end of the url.  I tried it with my original url and it worked fine.  2nd question, what is the "#cal-res-table a'"?  Thanks!!

Comment: Hiya - #cal-res-table a - the # is an css id selector so selects for a parent element with id cal-res-table. The space before the _a_ is a descendant combinator meaning that what comes next will be a child of that parent. The _a_ is a type selector for child _a_ tag.